# Compositions of equal a.e. functions with injective function need not be equal a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

Apparently there are measurable functions $f,g,h$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere, $h$ is injective, but we do *not* have $f \circ h = g \circ h$ almost everywhere. What is an example of such functions?

Comment: I guess this example should work: let f be the Dirichlet function, g be the zero function and h be the translation by an irrational number.

Comment: @Desperado, that composition would still be $0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: you're right, I miscomputed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prasiortle! My answer will rely upon some basic facts regarding the Cantor set $C.$

Consider $f := \chi_C,$ the indicator function of the Cantor set (since the Cantor set is measurable, so is $f$) and $g := 0.$ Since the measure of the Cantor set is zero, it follows that $f = g$ almost everywhere. Moreover, since the Cantor set is uncountable, there is some injective function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow C,$ which can of course be viewed as a function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (by composing it with the natural inclusion of the Cantor set into the reals). Then it is clear that $g \circ h = 0.$ On the other hand, $f \circ h (x) = \chi_C(h(x)) = 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ It follows that it is not true that $f \circ h = g \circ h$ almost everywhere, so this is an example of the behaviour you were looking for. Hope you will find this helpful.

Comment: There was also a hi there, don't know where it went haha